# What is python equivalent of php file_get_contents("php://input")

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, webapp2

I am trying to get post request raw data in python, can anyone tell me how? OR the equivalence method of file_get_contents("php://input") in Python?

Comment: Depends on what kind of server/backend etc you have running

Comment: I will be using google app engine to upload my application

Comment: What framework? webapp2?

Comment: yes, am using webapp2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a POST request's 'raw' data you do

```
class YourRequestHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        body = self.request.body
```

`body` now contains the POST request body where the request parameters are typically stored. This is usually a key-value pair which can be translated into a python dictionary for you with `json.loads(self.request.body)`

Answer (score 0):

`webapp2` uses `WebOb` internally so you can access the request body via `request.body`. See http://docs.webob.org/en/latest/reference.html#request-body